# Legend not showing all series in LightningChart JS

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Legend shows only series upto the height of chart. If height of chart is 500px legend's height is also 500px and thus remaining series value are not shown. How to show all series values in legend?

For example only 7 series names are being shown in chart even though the original data have 20 series. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying out between using either a Horizontal LegendBox and Vertical LegendBox builders. You can do this by passing a [LegendBoxBuilder](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/globals.html#legendboxbuilders) during legendBox creation

```js
// Align legendBox entries vertically, with groups aligned horizontally
const legendBox = chart.addLegendBox( LegendBoxBuilders.HorizontalLegendBox )
// Align legendBox entries horizontally, with groups aligned vertically
const legendBox = chart.addLegendBox( LegendBoxBuilders.VerticalLegendBox )
```

If this isn't enough, you can also try grouping the series in a legendBox, so they won't get aligned out of the chart area.

```js
// Add a series to a legendBox, attach it to a specific group
legendBox.add(
  // Series to attach to the legendBox.
  series1,
  // Boolean to set if clicking on the checkbox should hide/show the series attached.
  true,
  // Group name the entry should be grouped under; if no group with the name exists, it is created. If left empty, entry will be grouped under 'undefined group'.
  'Group 1'
)

// Add a series to a legendBox, set it to a second group
legendBox.add(
  series6,
  true,
  'Group 2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the information . But I am already adding the legend the way you suggested. @terhoLCJS